# Parallel execution of a function in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Below is parallel code. When I run I get the error - *UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df_project' referenced before assignment* 
I dont know what Im doing wrong. When I run the same code as a regular function it works fine.

Any inputs will be of great help

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def square(x):
    # calculate the square of the value of x
    v=x['content'][0]['template']['module']
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for i, v2 in enumerate(v): 
            df_project,df_module,df_module_header,df_module_paragraph,df_module_image,df_module_chart,df_module_chart_row,df_module_list = normalizeJSON(x,i,v2['id'])
    else:
        print('module is not a list')

    return df_project,df_module,df_module_header,df_module_paragraph,df_module_image,df_module_chart,df_module_chart_row,df_module_list

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Define the dataset
    dataset = result_list

    # Run this with a pool of 5 agents having a chunksize of 3 until finished
    agents = 5
    chunksize = 3
    project=pd.DataFrame()
    module=pd.DataFrame()
    content_module_columns=["module_id","module_text", "project_id", "project_revision","index"]  
    dim_content_module=pd.DataFrame(columns = content_module_columns)

    with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:
         project,module, module_header,module_paragraph,module_image,module_chart,module_chart_row,module_list=pool.map(square,dataset,chunksize)


Below is the normal (serial) version of the code that Im trying to parallelize 

    for index in range(len(result_list)):
        print('processing file number:', index)
        d=result_list[index]
        v=d['content'][0]['template']['module']
        if isinstance(v, list):
           for i, v2 in enumerate(v): 
               df_project,df_module = normalizeJSON(d,i,v2['id'])
               dim_content_module=dim_content_module.append(df_module, 
                                  ignore_index=True,sort=False)
        else:
            print('module is not a list')

I dont get any error in the serial version with the same input. 

*result_list* is a list of dictionaries
```

Comment: Before throwing this error, does it print "module is not a list"?

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: Assignment of that variable is in an `if` then a `for`. Suppose the `if` is false or the `for` has no items to conusme? Then you'll get that error. You need to work out your error paths for those cases.

Comment: @SamCarpenter No it didnt. I updated my question with the serial version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess without seeing full stack trace but most probably your problem is with this function:

```py
def square(x):
    # calculate the square of the value of x
    v=x['content'][0]['template']['module']
    if isinstance(v, list):
        for i, v2 in enumerate(v): 
            df_project,df_module,df_module_header,df_module_paragraph,df_module_image,df_module_chart,df_module_chart_row,df_module_list = normalizeJSON(x,i,v2['id'])
    else:
        print('module is not a list')

    return df_project,df_module,df_module_header,df_module_paragraph,df_module_image,df_module_chart,df_module_chart_row,df_module_list
```

Most likely that `isinstance` check returns `False` in one of the runs and when in `return` you're trying to use all these objects it throws `UnboundLocalError` because in fact you're referencing variables that were never assigned